# GameCenter Sandbox changes

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center, sandbox, leaderboard

As of "lately" according to this document : [Life Without Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2417/_index.html)

there is now only one server, the Production server (Sandbox server no longer exists). Also, I guess, there are still two sets of data but both are living on same (production) server.

So if I have this situation:

The game is on the store. Now I want to make an update, which require some debugging. Means, I will log in by using Sandbox Test account and eventually because of how game works, make some score, which will be sent to the leaderboard (highscore leaderboard).

The question is, would this score, made by Sandbox test account, be sent to GameCenter and shown among other scores made by regular players (which is unwanted) ?

If answer is no, then where the score will be saved while testing the game ?

One side question:

When game is already online, released, and you hit the "Delete test data" from iTunesConnect, what data would be actually deleted ? All data from GameCenter , or just records made by Sandbox test accounts, or something else?